Schematic Review of 14+14 watts TDA7269A Audio Amplifier

This a TDA7269 audio amp schematic which I made. It has two inputs for aux and BT and will run in single supply mode
Can someone please have a look and tell me if someting is wrong or missing which I should add or change since I am fairly new to pcb designing

Are you designing a product for a customer with a large order? Depending on volume, I'm fairly certain STMicro can support you under NDA.

No I am designing it for my own use

How is U18 supplied?

Separated U1A, U1B, and U1C (power) symbols. See the "Amp Power and Mute" box.

You've only connected one of the negative supply pins.

you are right but here the symbol in kicad has merged the pins 1 and 6 which are the negative supply pins

It appears to be an accurate reproduction of the typical application circuit given in the datasheet. Some observations:

The lack of a Rth(j-a) rating means that the 7269 will almost certainly require a substantial heatsink
If you do not intend to use the mute function, Q1 can be removed (short emitter to collector) and the entire 5V portion can be removed as well
If you are using the 7805 to power something through J4, then it will require an output capacitor and a heatsink (mandatory if the current draw is more than ~200mA, otherwise optional but a good idea; or use a switching converter)
At this scale, drawing your schematic with as much as possible explicitly connected instead of putting every "function" in a box and implicitly tying them together with net labels enhances readability


If i remove Q1 and the 5v supply then how would it play since according to the datasheet when the signal is 5v it plays.

Because the mute function is deactivated by pulling the mute pin at least 6V below Vs. The "typical application" schematic accommodates an external 5V signal from a microprocessor or something else but if you are not using the functionality, then you can just pull it down to ~3.5V - which is 8.5V below your Vs of 12V - with the combination of R7 and R8 (on your schematic). C8 and R9 prevent the "pop" on turn-on by temporarily muting the output.

So if i remove Q1 and use 16v as input will that be a problem? I would i think get 8v at mute is that ok?

That should not be a problem. I reiterate that removing Q1 means connecting C8 and R8 directly to R7. You may also omit D1.

Thanks for your help. Will be removing Q1 and keep the 7805 to power the bluetooth module

i checked it with a prototype circuit and found out that it works fine without Q1 but needs D1 as when i tried it without D1 there was no signal received by the amp
